# Denodo/VQL ISO_WEEK

Tags: iso, denodo, fiscal, vql

I wanted to work with iso week in Denodo. I could not find any functions or calculations.

I wanted to use this code below:

GETWEEK("ISO_WEEK", ADDWEEK(CURRENT_DATE(), 1))

Obviously there is no ISO_WEEK function. Have you encountered such a problem before?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you are looking to work with ISO weeks in Denodo and encountered an issue with the code using the "GETWEEK" function.

The "GETWEEK" function in Denodo follows the ISO standard and directly returns the day of the week as an integer. Therefore, you can use the function as follows:

GETWEEK(ADDWEEK(CURRENT_DATE(), 1))

This code will work without the need for the first argument "ISO_WEEK."

For more detailed information about the "GETWEEK" function and its usage, you can visit this link on the Denodo Community: [GETWEEK Function in Denodo](https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/6.0/vdp/vql/appendix/syntax_of_condition_functions/date_processing_functions#getweek).

Hope it helps